# Open-Vas Not Starting Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: boot, kali-linux

On my installation of Kali Linux 2.0, the Open Vulnerability Assessment System (Scanner|Manager) Daemon does not start successfully. It tells me to run the command `systemctl status openvas-scanner.service` for details. Here is the output:

```
● openvas-scanner.service - Open Vulnerability Assessment System Scanner Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvas-scanner.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2015-10-23 08:54:58 PDT; 1h 17min ago
     Docs: man:openvassd(8)
           http://www.openvas.org/
  Process: 747 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvassd --listen=127.0.0.1 --port=9391 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 23 08:54:58 kali systemd[1]: openvas-scanner.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 23 08:54:58 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start Open Vulnerability Assessment System Scanner Daemon.
Oct 23 08:54:58 kali systemd[1]: Unit openvas-scanner.service entered failed state.
```

If I am correct, this is the reason why `reaver` is not working properly on my Kali Linux. What can I do to solve this? I would greatly appreciate any feedback. If I need to add more information, please add a comment, and I will do so.

Comment: Can't help you with Openvas specifically but checking the load status of a unit in systemd is just not enough to understand the problem. I'm sure your syslog will have many hints as to what the problem really is.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by load status of a unit in systemd? And how can I check my syslog?

Comment: This is really very basic knowledge.. I strongly suggest you read more documentation or pick up a book on Linux before experimenting any further with something so complex as penetration testing. As for internet documentation, the Arch Linux Wiki is a great source of information. As for books, I can recommend "How Linux Works" by Brian Ward, though I'm sure there are many other good books around.

Comment: If you mean boot log, I know how to access that.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use follow command

1. openvas-setup
2. openvas-start

I think it is the problem that openvas didn't go a initial setup.
I have this problem but I search my command database use locate and then i find this command --- openvas-setup. you can try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature, not a bug. :)

Kali Linux' [policy](http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-network-service-policies) is to not start any networking services at boot. Openvas can't handle that, so it fails.

However, openvas has nothing to do with reaver.

Comment: Ok I already handled Open-Vas errors but what is wrong with my reaver?